# Display table on button click using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page that looks like this:
[image]

"Default List Name" is the name of the current page displayed. There are two buttons below and then a table which is the Default List table. Once I click `Btn1`, it will just re-display the default list table, but when I click `Btn2`, another table will be displayed, replacing the default list table. Let's call the second table "Second List". Once the table changes, the title "Default List Name" will also change to "Second List Name".

I am going to use AJAX for this so that real time button click and displaying of the corresponding table are applied. But I am still new to AJAX so I am having quite a hard time.

Here's my current code:

```
var title = $("#title").text();
var btn1 = $("#btn1");
var btn2 = $("#btn2");

/** If one of the buttons is clicked after another and then displays a table, the previous ajax that displayed the previous table, will be removed **/
$(document).ready(function() {
    btn1.on("click", function() {
        displayDefaultList();
    });
    btn2.on("click", function() {
        displaySecondList();
    });
});

function displayDefaultList(){
    console.log("display default list table");
    /*$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        url: 'url to current page (not sure)',
        async: false
    }).*/
}

function displaySecondList(){
    console.log("display second list table");
}
```

I hope I'm making my self clear and hope you guys can help me.

Comment: You can have a look at post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery?rq=1
if you really want to have control over the ajax requests, abort them when needed. 
**OR** 
you can disable the second button until loading bar is displayed while loading first table.

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/load

Comment: @Ethelene how you handle ajax response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wrote this for you just to show you that you can always show and hide your tables

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mytable1").show();
        $("#mytable2").hide();

        $("#button1").click(function(){
            $("#text").html("Default List Name");
            $("#mytable2").hide();
            $("#mytable1").show();

        });

        $("#button2").click(function(){
            $("#mytable1").hide();
            $("#mytable2").show();
            $("#text").html("Second List Name");
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "text">Default List Name</div>
<button id = "button1">Button1</button>
    <button id = "button2">Button2</button>
    <table  id = "mytable1" border = "1">
        <tr>
            <td>text1</td>
            <td>text1</td>
            <td>text1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>text2</td>
            <td>text2</td>
            <td>text2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>text3</td>
            <td>text3</td>
            <td>text3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>text4</td>
            <td>text4</td>
            <td>text4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 <br/>
    <table id = "mytable2" border = "1">
        <tr>
            <td>box1</td>
            <td>box1</td>
            <td>box1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>box2</td>
            <td>box2</td>
            <td>box2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>box3</td>
            <td>box3</td>
            <td>box3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>box4</td>
            <td>box4</td>
            <td>box4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

NOW for your ajax, you should just simply hide one of the tables based on the button that was clicked, and then load the data to your specific table. This works for me. Hope it helps :)

**Here's AJAX:**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#button1").click(function(){
        $("#mytable2").hide();

        $.ajax({
            url:'app.php',
            type: "GET",
            data: ""
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                    $("table #mytable1").append("<tr><td>" +
                                        "ID :" + value.ID +
                                        "Name :"+ value.Name +
                                        "Age :" + value.Age + 
                                        "</td><tr>");
                                       .........
                });
            }
        });
    });


    $("#button2").click(function(){
        $("#mytable1").hide();

        $.ajax({
            url:'app.php',
            type: "GET",
            data: ""
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                    $("table #mytable2").append("<tr><td>" +
                                        "ID :" + value.ID +
                                        "Name :"+ value.Name +
                                        "Age :" + value.Age + 
                                        "</td><tr>");
                                       .........
                });
            }
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out.

Comment: @EtheleneLaverne if it works out for you which I'm sure it will you can always accept the answer :). Thanks!

Comment: It works now. But I still have another issue with PHP, which I may raise in another question. Thanks! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108881/discussion-between-ethelene-laverne-and-henrydev).

Answer (score 1):

I created this fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/8bakcfub/.

Basically, each button click will simulate a call to an API that returns a very simple JSON object. On success, the code parses the response, empties the table and appends a new row to it with the data, and finally changes the title.

Note that the code is pretty much the same for both buttons, except for (a) the JSON returned from AJAX, and (b) the title :)

HTML:

```
<p id="title">
  This title will be replaced...
</p>
<button id="btn1">
  First list
</button>
<button id="btn2">
  Second list
</button>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var btn1 = $("#btn1");
var btn2 = $("#btn2");

$(document).ready(function() {
  btn1.on("click", function() {
    displayDefaultList();
  });
  btn2.on("click", function() {
    displaySecondList();
  });
});

function displayDefaultList() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/echo/json/',
    async: false,
    data: {
      json: JSON.stringify({
        row: [1, 2]
      })
    },
    success: function(result) {
      $('#title').text('first list');
      $('#table tbody').remove();
      var newRow = '<tbody><tr><td>' + result.row[0] + '</td></tr><tr><td>' + result.row[1] + '</td></tr></tbody>';
      $('#table').append(newRow);
    }
  });
}

function displaySecondList() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/echo/json/',
    async: false,
    data: {
      json: JSON.stringify({
        'row': [3, 4]
      })
    },
    success: function(result) {
      $('#title').text('second list');
      $('#table tbody').remove();
      var newRow = '<tbody><tr><td>' + result.row[0] + '</td></tr><tr><td>' + result.row[1] + '</td></tr></tbody>';
      $('#table').append(newRow);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But what exactly is inside `url: '/echo/json/'`?

Comment: The URL in there is the URL of the web service that will return JSON data for you to store in the table